# Dsplay the coupon code in an opencart product page

Tags: opencart, coupon

Please help me to display the coupon code or coupon name in opencart 2.1.0.1 product page. For the promotion of products I need to display the coupons or promo code in the product page of opencart 2.1.0.1.

Comment: What exactly do you want to display and where?

Comment: particular product with coupon code which is adding in the marketing-> coupon should be displayed in the product main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be hard coded, you will have to add a method to the copoun model which will take the product_id and return the copouns related to this product_id, then in the product controller you will need to call this method and list the copouns in a data variable, then in the product view you need to show them in the desired place.